# Python3 Default Data Type Argument Syntax Error

Tags: python

I was coding to learn some basic OOP in Python and I ran into an error. The constructor is giving me an syntax error.

```
class Item: 
    def __init__(self, name: str, price: float, quantity=5):
        # Run validations to received arguments
        assert price >= 0, f"Price {price} is not greater than or equal to 0!"
        assert quantity >= 0, f"Quantity {quantity} is not greater than or equal to 0!"
```

The error: [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wMwxW.png)

Weirdly enough, this code has no Syntax errors when I try to run it on an online Python interperter. Also, if needed, the constructor is line 5 and Syntax Error is stated on line 5 (constructor **init** line).

This most likely is a silly mistakes that I can't seem to find.

Thank you ahead of time StackOverflow community.

I was expecting to not get any errors and it to run simply i.e., make sure that name of my Item class was a string and not a float or any other data type.

Comment: There is no error visible in the image.

Comment: Can you provide more error details, instead of just the method screenshot like the output or error that is produced when you try to run the program.

Comment: This type of intransparent (badly located by the error message) SyntaxError most often occurs when you are missing a closing  parentheses `)` at the end of the previous line.

Comment: Can't reproduce :( python 3.9.6

Comment: Hey, I just updated the Error Screenshot.

Comment: You appear to be running this under Python 2.x, which didn't support type annotations.

Answer (score -1):

You're using the Python version 2. Run it again using the `python3` (if installed) command:

[image]

As mentioned by @jasonharper, type annotations are not supported in Python 2.